# Left third of iPad screen is blocked with bookmarks column

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, bookmarks

⅓ of my screen is blocked on the left by a Bookmarks column. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Click on the bookmark icon (looks like a book) to hide the bookmarks

Answer (score 5):

Tap the bookmarks icon in the toolbar to hide the bookmarks. The button is blue when the bookmarks list is shown.

> [image]

https://www.howtoisolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/2-Bookmark-panel-in-safari.jpg